# how to stop backspace from redirecting to a blank page?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am working on a JSP page and whenever i place the cursor on a disabled textbox and hit backspace on my keyboard i get a blank screen. How do I solve this problem?

I have already tried using the "readonly" attribute but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

You can control this behavior by calling `event.preventDefault();` in-case of back button pressed using `keydown` event of the `readOnly` fields as following:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="search" readOnly />
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery('#search').bind('keydown', function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '8')
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/d4ztud99/2/)